# NEL MEZZO MI RITROVA CHE LA DRITTA

Tags: meaning

I have a marble bust that has the inscription: NEL MEZZO MI RITROVA CHE LA DRITTA. Struggling with getting the right sense. Assistence requested.

Comment: It is very strange, it means nothing. May be it is a wrong sentence, coming from the beginning of the *Commedia* di Dante "Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita -
Mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,-
-Che la diritta via era smarrita. "

Comment: I agree with @BakerStreet. These are the first syllables of the first three verses of Dante's *Inferno*. Well, in fact, *va* in RITROVA should be *vai*.

Comment: ...and DRITTA should be DIRITTA. So, yes, the first few words of the first lines of the _Inferno_ with some misspellings.

Answer (score 7):

This should be completed (and fixed) into the tercet

> NEL MEZZO [DEL CAMMIN DI NOSTRA VITA]
> MI RITROVA[I PER UNA SELVA OSCURA,]
> CHE LA DIRITTA [VIA ERA SMARRITA.]

which is the very famous beginning of the “Comedia” (nowadays mostly known as “La divina commedia”) by Dante Alighieri, possibly the most important Italian poem, because modern Italian is basically founded upon it.

The sentence “nel mezzo mi ritrova che la dritta” means nothing, but it obviously suggests the three verses above to anybody who has studied a bit of Italian literature.